# Does Firefox 6 support CSS 3D Transforms?

Tags: firefox, css, 3d, transform

Hi I can't determine if CSS3D Transforms work on Firefox 6. More importantly, are 3D transforms necessary in FF if you want to get the benefits of the GPU as you do in webkit or has the FF team implemented GPU acceleration on 2D transforms as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 3d transform support in Firefox 6, but 2d transforms should be gpu-accelerated so you don't have to do the 3d hackery, yes.

Comment: Any source that confirms this? Or way to test?

Comment: Nevermind. I verified this on twitter: https://twitter.com/louis_remi/status/104197200715841536

(at)robertnyman (at)paul_irish (at)jimjeffers Bad side effect of translateZ(0) trick: now devs think 3d transform are required for HWAccel. It's not!

(at)robertnyman (at)paul_irish (at)jimjeffers Answer is: Firefox will use HWAccel if your hardware and platform is supported, even w/o ANY transform

Answer (score 1):

No. Not yet. http://caniuse.com/#search=3dtransform

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Firefox 10, 3dtransforms via css3 is supported. Using `-moz` prefixes instead of `-webkit` in all your CSS attributes is required, of course.